# How to normalize string in PHP for desired output?

Tags: php, string

Having some trouble normalizing some strings in PHP...

Given these test cases:

- Van Fleur, Pat
- Smith,John K
- Smith, John Jr.
- Smith,Jose Jr

I am attempting to normalize names in a list that use the format: Lastname,Firstname

Expected output for the test cases:

- Van Fleur,Pat
- Smith,John
- Smith,John
- Smith,Jose

I am using the following line, but appears I'm only getting a subset of these test cases accounted for.

Using this: `strtok(trim(strtolower($name)), ' ')`

I'm not great at regex, so really haven't ventured down that road yet.

Can you assist me with achieving the desired output using either regex or native functions?

Comment: Maybe interesting: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: Cool article, but this is a very specific use case and the "rules" above have been vetted for my purposes.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, are you asking for help on writing a code that would remove the space after comma and remove the middle initials like `Jr`?

Comment: Yes... input is the first set of test cases... and looking for function or regex to convert each test case to the desired output test case.

Comment: You have receive more than one legitimate answer to your question.  Please accept the answer that best helped you and upvote any answer that you found helpful.  This will deem your question to be "answered" by the Stackoverflow software and this is a way of rewarding the volunteers to gave their time to help you in your time of need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way around that, you need to somehow iterate over that data array and convert each entry:

```
<?php

$data = [
  'Van Fleur, Pat', 
  'Smith,John K', 
  'Smith, John Jr.', 
  'Smith,Jose Jr'
];

array_walk($data, function($value, $key) use (&$data) {
  preg_match('|\s*(\w.+),\s*(\w+)|', $value, $token);
  $data[$key] = sprintf('%s,%s', $token[1], $token[2]);
});

print_r($data);
```

The output obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Van Fleur,Pat
    [1] => Smith,John
    [2] => Smith,John
    [3] => Smith,Jose
)
```

---

An obvious alternative is something like that:

```
<?php

$input = [
  'Van Fleur, Pat', 
  'Smith,John K', 
  'Smith, John Jr.', 
  'Smith,Jose Jr'
];

$output =  array_map(function($value) {
  preg_match('|\s*(\w.+),\s*(\w+)|', $value, $token);
  return sprintf('%s,%s', $token[1], $token[2]);
}, $input);

print_r($output);
```

But be careful here, such an approach won't scale well, since you actually *double* the memory footprint of the data that way...

---

So maybe that alternative would even be more elegant, since just as the first example it does an in-place change of the entries:

```
<?php

$data = [
  'Van Fleur, Pat', 
  'Smith,John K', 
  'Smith, John Jr.', 
  'Smith,Jose Jr'
];

foreach($data as &$entry) {
  preg_match('|\s*(\w.+),\s*(\w+)|', $entry, $token);
  $entry = sprintf('%s,%s', $token[1], $token[2]);
}

print_r($data);
```

---

Considering your comment below which describes a slightly different scenario I would add this suggestion:

```
 $entry = preg_replace('|^\s*(\w.+),\s*(\w+)\s*.*$|', '$1,$2', $entry);
```

Comment: Omg a useful answer on SO! To be clear, I am iterating over a list of these names already, so will test each case individually.

Comment: In that case you can simply apply one of the `preg_...()` functions. Maybe you even get away with an immediate `preg_replace()` application.

Answer (score 0):

Capture the leading substring until the `,`, then match (but don't capture) the comma and optional space, then greedily capture non-space characters, then just match the rest of the string so that the replacement value overwrites the full original value.

Using negated character classes speeds up the pattern.  Here is a simple one-call method:

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fba93l/1)

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1b09540f953520e4c880e38a687c4a1095efc32d))

```
$names=[
  'Van Fleur, Pat', 
  'Smith,John K', 
  'Smith, John Jr.', 
  'Smith,Jose Jr'
];

$names=preg_replace('/([^,]+), ?([^ ]+).*/','$1,$2',$names);
var_export($names);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Van Fleur,Pat',
  1 => 'Smith,John',
  2 => 'Smith,John',
  3 => 'Smith,Jose',
)
```

---

Let's consider some more complex hypothetical inputs -- including names that don't need correcting.

```
Van Fleur, Pat                          // <-- 1 replacement
Smith,Josiah                            // <-- nothing to fix
Smith,John K                            // <-- 1 replacement
Smith,John Jacob Jingleheimer           // <-- 1 long replacement
O'Shannahan-O'Neil, Sean Patrick Eamon  // <-- double surname with apostrophes
de la Cruz, Bethania                    // <-- 3-word surname
Smith, John Jr.                         // <-- 2 replacements
Smith,Jose Jr                           // <-- 1 replacement
```

You can use my first posted pattern which is an efficient pattern, but it will execute replacements on names that do not require any fixes.

Alternatively, you can use this "capture-less" pattern: `/,\K | [^,]*$/` with an empty replacement string.  This will use many more steps, but will avoid performing needless replacing.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bddd30fb5e9d09af093b2ce8fdc4f0871af1edae))

```
$names=preg_replace('/,\K | [^,]*$/','',$names);
var_export($names);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Van Fleur,Pat',
  1 => 'Smith,Josiah',
  2 => 'Smith,John',
  3 => 'Smith,John',
  4 => 'O\'Shannahan-O\'Neil,Sean',
  5 => 'de la Cruz,Bethania',
  6 => 'Smith,John',
  7 => 'Smith,Jose',
)
```

Lastly, if you have some deep-seated hate for regex (I certainly don't), you can use this method:

```
foreach($names as &$name){
    $parts=explode(',',$name);
    $name=$parts[0].','.explode(' ',ltrim($parts[1]),2)[0];
}
unset($name);  // this is not required, but many recommend it to prevent issues downscript
var_export($names);
```

The decision about which one is best for your project, will come down to the quality of your real data and your personal tastes.  I suggest running some comparative speed tests if optimization is a priority.

Comment: maybe i am wrong but wont your regex capture the name `Van Fleur, Pat` too, which should not be captured, https://regex101.com/r/Av8Tfn/2

Comment: Huh?  @Muhammad the OP does want that.  I don't understand your concern.

Comment: @SourceMatters Okay, I think I've baked in as many considerations as I can.  Let me know if you would like clarification on any of my points/snippets.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
^([^\,]+)\,\s?([^\s]+)
```